# That vs Which usage

Tags: word-choice, which-that

> Iraq was first destroyed by the U.S. military and now it's being reconstructed by the U.S. corporations, **which** were the cause of its deliberate destruction.

Can we use *that* instead of *which* here?

Answer (score 2):

**Can we use "that" instead of "which" here** - probably not.

In this usage ***that*** introduces a *defining* clause, i.e. one that modifies and restricts the meaning of the immediately preceding noun. Because a *that* clause is essential (critical) in defining and restricting the noun, it is NOT normally preceded by a comma.

***Which*** is generally used to introduce a *descriptive* clause, i.e. one that adds additional information, but is *not essential* to the meaning of the sentence. Being optional - rather than essential - to the sentence, a *which* clause IS normally preceded by a comma.

*Which* clauses are sometimes used as *defining* clauses, in the same way as *that* clauses, in which case they should NOT be preceded by a comma.

I find the sentence in question somewhat ambiguous:

> *Iraq ... [is now] ... being reconstructed by **the** U.S. corporations, which were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

because of the highlighted word ***the***.

If you omit that word:

> *... being reconstructed by U.S. corporations, which were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

I read it as meaning that it is

> *... being reconstructed by U.S. corporations [in general], [**some of**] which were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

But with ***the*** U.S. corporations, it invites the following clause to define which particular U.S. corporations are being referred to - in other words, it *requires* a defining clause. In that case, ***that*** or ***which*** - but *without* the preceding comma - would be appropriate:

> *... being reconstructed by **the** U.S. corporations **that** were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

Grammatically, that makes sense and would be correct, but I doubt that the sentence is actually intended to mean that the reconstruction is being carried out either *solely by* nor *by all of* those particular *U.S. corporations that were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

So my answer would be that the quoted sentence is actually ambiguous, but I suspect that the intended meaning is:

> *Iraq ... [is now] ... being reconstructed by U.S. corporations, **some of which** were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

rather than:

> *Iraq ... [is now] ... being reconstructed by **the** [i.e. those particular] U.S. corporations **that** were the cause of its deliberate destruction.*

Comment: See also [restrictive vs non-restrictive relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html).